# Criteria or dynamic finder to retrieve like/unlike status of a status update item in grails

Tags: grails, social-networking, criteria

how to set like and unlike of the status depending on whether user has liked it already or not? do i need to use criteria or dynamic finder or each loop in gsp to find out like and unlike?

My app's model looks like this:

`Status` domain has many `likes`
`like` belongs to `user` and `status`
`user` has many `status` and `likes`

```
 <g:each in="${statusInstanceList}" status="i" var="statusInstance">
 ${fieldValue(bean: statusInstance, field: "statusMessage")}

 <g:each var="likeInstance" in="${statusInstance.like}">
  <g:set var="likesSize" value="${statusInstance.like?.size()}"/>
   $likesSize
 </g:each>

 </g:each>
```

`$likesSize` outputs the counts of the likes a status has. (thanks to @dmahapatro)

I need to find out, if the session user has liked the status already or not and show like / unlike on its basis.

Update: now I get unlike and like if i use below if statement
how can i limit it to show only unlike or like?

```
<g:each in="${statusInstance.like?.userAccountId}" status="p" var="userlike">
                      <g:if test="${userlike == session.selectedUser?.id || statusInstance.like?.statusId == statusInstance.id}">
                        Unlike
                      </g:if>
                      Like
                      </g:each>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am just throwing out an idea:

`user.like` would give you all the likes of an user.
`status.like` would give you all the likes of a status.

Would you not be able to find out whether an user's like is also a status' like?

You need to find out a `Like` which belongs to both `User` and `Status`.

Comment: yes, so to get that should i run a criteria for this? or will dynamic finder be able to do that for me?
or is there any other method i should use?

Comment: Dynamic finder is the simplistic approach, I feel. Criteria/HQL is used when you have various associations and you want all of them eagerly. Again, whatever you do, have it in the controller and set that to model which can be accessed in the view layer instead of having tons of groovy code in gsp. :)

Comment: Please check the bottom part of the main question? Update! @dmahapatro

Comment: but It gets confusing when i need to show statuses on different view model then status itself. status wont load if try to if i simply pass it via model to that view.
how call criteria in one controller from different controller.
:(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use a simple dynamic finder for this.

```
Like.findByUserAndStatus(user, status)
```

If this returns a result, then the user has liked the status.

Comment: Please check the bottom part of the main question? Update!
@Adam